# Out- of range overflow handling in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, google-cloud-sql

I'm using cloud SQL. I want to handle the out of range overflow using a stored procedure.

So, I used

```
SET sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
```

Created sample table with int, decimal and varchar

```
CREATE TABLE t4 (ii INT, dd DECIMAL(5,2), ff VARCHAR(5));
```

Procedure 1:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SAMPLE_SQL_MODE1;
CREATE PROCEDURE `SAMPLE_SQL_MODE1`(ii INT,dd DECIMAL(5,2),ff varchar(5))
BEGIN
    SET sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES';

    INSERT INTO t4 VALUES (ii, dd, ff);

    SELECT * FROM t4;
    SELECT @@sql_mode;
END;

call SAMPLE_SQL_MODE1(12344444444,12344.33,'Nummber FIVE');
```

Procedure 1 result:

```
 select * from t4;  

 max of int , decimal(5,2) inserted.

--------   --------  -------
 ii            dd       ff
--------   --------   -------
 2147483647 999.99    Nummb
----------  -------  -------
```

Procedure 2:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SAMPLE_SQL_MODE2;
CREATE PROCEDURE `SAMPLE_SQL_MODE2`()
BEGIN
    SET sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES';

    INSERT INTO t4 (ii, dd, ff) 
    VALUES (12344444444, 12344.33, 'Nummber FIVE');

    SELECT * FROM t4;
    SELECT @@sql_mode;
END;

call SAMPLE_SQL_MODE2();
```

Procedure 2 result:

```
Out of range value for column 'ii' at row 1
```

Please help me. How to use set sql mode= ='STRICT_ALL_TABLES' inside the stored procedure?

I'm using all my procedures likes `Procedure 1` but the `sql_mode` does not throw  an error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first stored procedure is accepting an argument of an integer.  The problem is that the *call* to the stored procedure does the "conversion" *before* the stored procedure takes effect.  Presumably, the sql mode is not strict outside the stored procedure.  So, the arguments look valid when the SQL mode is in effect.

Here are two options:

1. Change the arguments to hold bigger values, such as `BIGINT` and `VARCHAR(255)`.  Then the conversions should cause a failure.
2. Change the code to set strict mode *before* the call to the procedure.